# Create a node in scala

Tags: scala

I want to implement a list in scala.

Therefore, I want to implement a node first.

in other languages we can say

```
typedef node<T> ([T] value, node[T] *next)
```

How is it possible to do something like this in scala?

Comment: I like when someone downvotes my question, (which I do not think is that strange for a person new in Scala), but no explanation is given, and no answer is given as well

Comment: I think you are looking for something like this: `case class Node[T](value: T, next: Node[T])`

Comment: Thanks a lot @serejja.:) I will try that in a few minutes

Comment: I would consider setting up `next` as an `Option[Node[T]]` as terminal nodes will not have a next

Comment: Also, I did not down vote you, but fwiw my guess is its because you did not show any effort at all in attempting to solve this problem yourself first

Comment: @cmbaxter Thanks for your comment. I searched both on Google and Stackoverflow, and both of them, were showing results on how to create an XML node!! So I posted here, as my search did not helped...

Comment: search tip: rather than "node", you'd probably find more information with "building trees" or "representing graphs".

Answer (score 1):

In Scala you would use a class to represent both a node and a terminal node:

```
sealed abstract class ListNode[+T]
final class ListTerminal extends ListNode[Nothing]
final case class MyList[T](head: T, tail: ListNode[T]) extends ListNode[T]
```

You can use it this way:

```
object Main {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val l1 = ListTerminal
    val l2: MyList[Int] = List(3, l1)
    val l3: MyList[Any] = List("a", l2)
  }
}
```

As you can see, correct use of types and variance let scala go up and down the type hierarchy in a safe manner (indeed, the type annotations on `l2` and `l3` are optional).
As always, your custom implementation can leverage this or fall back to the default (good) Scala List!

Comment: i'd be a little cautious of defining a type `List`, as it will almost certainly cause reader confusion with the collections library's List

Comment: You're right, I've now defined it as 'MyList'! (trust me, on friday afternoon while working I'm not able to come up with a better name! :D )

Comment: You also have to change it to `MyList` in the `Main`. `val l2: MyList[Int] = MyList(3, l1)` etc